# Chat oneboxing of GitHub's Gists is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

> gists used to have numeric IDs, now they don't, so it doesn't match the gist regex on master_chat.js - [Unihedro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622940/unihedro), [JavaScript Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21129147#21129147)

Could this be fixed so that Gists onebox properly again?

Comment: Alternatively, make Github Gists use numeric IDs again, I personally dislike UUID. They really do suck.

Comment: @Unihedro I doubt that Github will change just to cater for SO. And alphanumeric IDs are much denser

Comment: Private gists have always used non-integer IDs. I guess those have never been supported? (Also, these new ones aren't UUIDs -- those are 16 bytes, these are only 10, like a SHA-1 digest.)

Comment: This is not the place for GitHub bug reports (your question title may be inaccurate, perhaps "chat oneboxing of GitHub gists is broken"?)

Comment: @Ben I thought that "oneboxing" is a term local to SE chat; I'll edit the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in chat build 314. Enjoy!

(Oops, in testing this out in Sandbox, it looks like we've hit GitHub's API quota. So still no gist displays (whether old-style or new-style) until the quota resets. But it does work for me locally, I promise.)